# Authorize.Net Query on recurring billing

Tags: authorize.net, recurring-billing

We have been trying to integrate authorize.net payment gateway in one of our clients project based on Asp.net web API. We have few queries that we came across while implementing Recurring Planning scenarios.

Query 1
We checked the API’s for Creating Subscription, Getting Subscription, Updating Subscription. However once we have created subscription, is there any way we can update the amount in the subscription.
Let’s say for example.
We have a created a subscription for our user for 50$ amount on 01st Jan 2021 with 30 days interval.
And on 15th Jan 2021, our user wishes to purchase 1 more license which will cost him 10$ more.
Hence can we increase his billing cycle of subscription by updating the subscription?
We checked in Update Subscription API, & it is only allowing to update credit card info hence is there any way to update amount.

Query 2
Is there any way to implement Autorenewal, hence when a user wishes he/she can set auto renewal on/off for recurring billing.

Query 3
If there is any way to switch off auto renewal of recurring billing, then is there any link that we can generate & send them through which they can pay there next due.

Answer (score 1):

Query 1: You cannot update a subscription amount. If the amount needs to change you either need to cancel the current subscription and create a new one for the new amount (being sure to prorate credit from the previous subscription payment) or use CIM to manage your subscription service which allows you to charge against their card at your discretion but requires you to also manage the subscription yourself.

Query 2: Not through Authorize.Net. If you want a subscription to start or end you need to explicitly do so through their API.

Query 3: Not through Authorize.Net. That application logic and, once again, you would be responsible for managing.

Comment: regarding your comment on using CIM..  So does that mean, we can make payment or create a new subscription based on credit card details provided earlier without user's concern or authorization

Comment: Yes if you create a customer profile using CIM. Then you can create the subscription from that payment profile.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are using or are aware of the API provided for Authorize.net here: https://github.com/AuthorizeNet/sdk-dotnet/tree/master/Authorize.NET/Api/Controllers

Query 1: As of now, there is a way to update the amount for a given subscription. You can use ARBSubscriptionType class. There is an amount property there you can set. Then you can create the request ARBUpdateSubscriptionRequest, passing in the ARBSubscriptionType class and the subscription Id.

Note: You might have to handle pro-rating.

Query 2: There isn't a built in renewal feature in Authorize.Net as far as I know. It seems like you could potentially update the totalOccurrences by some amount to act as a "renewal", when technically its an extension of the subscription. The method in which you check when to update, either a Modulo operation or a date check is up to you. You can use paymentScheduleType class to update totalOccurrences, passing it along to a ARBUpdateSubscriptionRequest.

Query 3: Authorize.Net does not have any in house link generation.